# Extract date from file name

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to extract the date from a filename and storing it to a variable and also needs to change the date format . If I have the name of the file consistent, can I go by position and extract the date?

```
File Name: GHDC_src_04142019_05_09_32.data.gz
```

looking the result of that date

```
04142019 as var=2019-04-14
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can "go by position," try:

```
$ name=GHDC_src_04142019_05_09_32.data.gz
$ echo "${name:13:4}-${name:9:2}-${name:11:2}"
2019-04-14
```

Or, to save in a variable:

```
name=GHDC_src_04142019_05_09_32.data.gz
var="${name:13:4}-${name:9:2}-${name:11:2}"
```

Since this uses pure bash, no subprocess needs to be started and no external command needs to be launched.  This makes this approach efficient.

The form `${name:offset:length}` is called *substring expansion*.  It selects characters from `$name` starting at `offset` and continuing for `length`.  In our case, `${name:13:4}` captures the year, `${name:9:2}` the month, and `${name:11:2}` the day.